# Initializing only one row of 2-D array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

I have an array with two rows, the first of which contains all the prime numbers up to 997. The second row should contain all 0s at initialization, as they will be given values later through a for-loop. However, when I initialize the array in the following manner:

```
nt prime(int numfac[2][168], int num){
int j = 0, i = 0;
int numfac[][] = {
                  {2,3,5,7,1,13,17,19,
                   23,29,31,37,41,43,
                   47,53,59,61,67,71,
                   73,79,83,89,97,101,
                   103,107,109,113,127,
                   131,137,139,149,151,
                   157,163,167,173,179,
                   181,191,193,197,199,
                   211,223,227,229,233,
                   239,241,251,257,263,
                   269,271,277,281,283,
                   293,307,311,313,317,
                   331,337,347,349,353,
                   359,367,373,379,383,
                   389,397,401,409,419,
                   421,431,433,439,443,
                   449,457,461,463,467,
                   479,487,491,499,503,
                   509,521,523,541,547,
                   557,563,569,571,577,
                   587,593,599,601,607,
                   613,617,619,631,641,
                   643,647,653,659,661,
                   673,677,683,691,701,
                   709,719,727,733,739,
                   743,751,757,761,769,
                   773,787,797,809,811,
                   821,823,827,829,839,
                   853,857,859,863,877,
                   881,883,887,907,911,
                   919,929,937,941,947,
                   953,967,971,977,983,
                   991,997},
                   {0}
                   };
```

my compiler returns: "array type has incomplete element type".

How can one initialize only one row of a two-dimensional array in C? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might list the compiler error you get.  I suspect it has to do with you providing only one value for the second row, rather than 168 values.

Comment: @Dweeberly - Edited with compiler error. I thought if you initialize fewer than the number of elements in an array, the rest are automatically initialized to 0?

Comment: You may well be right, thus my request for the compiler error.  What you have looks an awful lot like an initialization of a "ragged array" and the compiler may be getting confused.  ... It's very late where I'm at :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to initialize 168 columns in one row.

Ex.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 168; i ++)
{
    numfac[1][i] = 0;
}
```

It's important to note that an array declared numfac[2][168] will actually contain elements [0,1] and [0,1,2...167]. In addition, if a value is not set, then it will be NULL which will cause serious miscalculations.

Comment: What would this actually do? I don't understand what the line numfac[1][i] = 0; does. I need the elements in the first row to be the primes up to 997, not sure how I could do that through a for-loop. I think the code you gave me would initialize the second row to be all zeroes, is that right?

Comment: This is in answer to your question "How can one initialize only one row of a two dimmensional array in c?" By using this for loop, it initializes every column of a single row to be zeroes as you said.

Comment: "if a value is not set, then it will be NULL" that is not true unless it's static.

Comment: In C, if a variable isn't declared with a specific value, it could be almost anything, if memory wasn't flushed properly. :B